# How should I change my code to chain generator function by using ES6 proxy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I've been spending many hours for the last couple days to make my code work but I can't make it work!!

What I'm trying to accomplish is chaining generator functions like the below by using es6 proxy. It seems that I can add these list operation functions to generator prototype but I want to use proxy instead for my study purpose.

## Something that I want to acheive in the end

```
rangeGenerator
    .map('project function here')
    .filter('predicate function here')
    .forEach('do some last work');
```

Could anyone please take a look at my code below and tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix this, please?

Thanks!!

## My Code

```
function range(end) {
    return function* rangeGf() {
        for (let i = 1; i <= end; i++) {
             yield i;
        }
    }
}

const makeHandler = (options) => {

    const handler = {
        get: function(target, property, resolver) {
            if (property === 'map') {
                return map.bind(target);
            }

            if (property === 'filter') {
                return filter.bind(target);
            }
        }
    };

    function map(project) {
        console.log('project', project);
        const newTarget = this;

        function* mapGf() {
            for (let v of newTarget()) {
                yield v * 2; //hard coding for now...
            }
        }
        // return generator object wrapped by proxy
        return new Proxy(mapGf(), handler);
    }

    function filter(predicate) {
        console.log('predicate', predicate);
        const newTarget = this;

        function* filterGf() {
            for (let v of newTarget) {
                if(v % 3 === 0) { //hard coding for now...
                    yield v; 
                }
            }
        }

        // return generator object wrapped by proxy
        return new Proxy(filterGf(), handler);
    } 

    return handler;

};

const rangeGf = range(10);

const $range = new Proxy(rangeGf, makeHandler())

// for now, I'm trying to make this simple one work!
for (var i of $range.map('project')) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

## For now, I want to make this part work

```
for (var i of $range.map('project')) {
    console.log(i)
}
```

Comment: Where do you define `handler`?

Comment: It's in the code above already, but let me move it up.

Comment: I suspect the for loop used in `rangeGf()` might be an issue, it looks like you're trying to use `let` to make `i` "static" - but I think this will just cause your `rangeGf()` generators to always just yield 1.  I think you probably can't use a `for` loop here, even if `i` retains it's value between invocations of the generator, since it will never reach the increment expression

Comment: Using a proxy here makes no sense - you don't need to handle arbitrary property accesses, you know exactly which properties you need. You should just put the methods on the instance, using a factory or a subclass or by extending the native prototype.

Comment: @Bergi thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Bergi is it bad to use proxy for this?

Comment: @shu Yes, I think it's bad (unnecessarily complex, and probably much slower). It's just YAGNI.